When printing a single-page PDF with multiple copies, Xreader prints a blank page after each copy
When printing a single-page PDF with multiple copies, Xreader prints a blank page after each copy.
This doesn't occur with multi-page PDFs. The work-around is to edit the single-page PDF to have multiple duplicate pages (two, for example) and print that the appropriate multiple of times.
Weirdness may be caused by printing to a custom paper size.
Is there a fix?
Mint 21.2, kernel 5.15.0-122, MATE 1.26.0, Xreader 3.8.5

The problem here is trying to two-sided print a small format piece of paper. The printer tries its best, but decides it can't flip the paper successfully so the best way to double-sided print your single page document is to print the first page one the first sheet, and the reverse side of the single-sided document on the second sheet. This is why an even multiple of pages will print without a blank page.
Printer in question is a Brother HL-L2375DW

